# Fast I2C connection, moving to new library

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266

I need a faster communication between the ESP and the ADC, so I found this https://github.com/pasko-zh/brzo_i2c.

**Original Wire Example**

```
#include "Wire.h"
#define PCF8591 0x48
byte a0;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(13,14);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(PCF8591);
  Wire.write(0x04);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  Wire.requestFrom(PCF8591, 5);
  a0=Wire.read();
  a0=Wire.read();
  Serial.println(a0);
  delay(1000);
}
```

**Brzo I2C example**

```
#include "brzo_i2c.h"

uint8_t buffer[10];
uint8_t error=0;
float temp=0.0;

uint8_t ICACHE_RAM_ATTR get_temp(float *t) {
   uint8_t bcode=0;
  brzo_i2c_start_transaction(0x48,400);
  buffer[0]=0x04; 
  brzo_i2c_write(buffer,1,false);// somewhere here is the error
  brzo_i2c_read(buffer,2,false);// or here
  bcode=brzo_i2c_end_transaction();
  *t=((buffer[0]<<8)|buffer[1]);
  return bcode;
}

void setup(){
  delay(500);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  brzo_i2c_setup(13,14,2000);
}

void loop() {
  error=get_temp(&temp);
  if(error==0){
  Serial.print("Temp = ");
  Serial.println(temp, 8);
} else {
  Serial.print("Brzo error : ");
  Serial.println(error);
}
  delay(500);
}
```

**But I always get the same error.**

> 1 : Bus not free

I rewrote it in different ways, changing the frequency, pins and doing multiple transactions. The main reason I don't get it to work is the difference in the API.

There is no ~Wire.requestFrom();`in the brzo_i2c lib. So I need to read the value with`brzo_i2c_read(buffer,2,false);`. Anyway, the brzo code does not work. I always get the same error and there is no description in the docs.

Wire reference: https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/wire

brzo reference: https://github.com/pasko-zh/brzo_i2c/wiki

Comment: Do you have a question? I think you should examine the docs for that library thoroughly and check what the error message means.

Comment: Yes, the brzo code does not work. The docs/error says "Bus is not free". nothing else is explained.

Comment: what is `Wire`? What does `Wire.requestFrom` do? Are you sure the error comes from the call to `bzro_i2c_read`?

Comment: Basically i'm trying to figure out ho i could write "Wire.requestFrom();" using the new library. BUT i'm not even able to get to that line.

Comment: What's "original wire"? What's `Wire.h`?

Comment: there errors come from "brzo_i2c_end_transaction()" but they always do. even if there is a different error in another function inside the transaction the error is outputted from that function.

Comment: wire is the original library used to make arduino's and esp8266's work with various communication systems. like i2c SPI ..

Comment: Wire.requestFrom() reads from a specific address (i2c) a number of bytes in sequence. Wire.requestFrom(address,numberofbytes)

Answer (score 4):

This is paško, the author of the library `brzo_i2c`.

First, for further upcoming questions may I kindly ask you to open an issue on the github repo, i.e. [bzro_i2c Issues](https://github.com/pasko-zh/brzo_i2c/issues). This is the usual place where people ask questions about the library.

I made a distinction between documentation of the code and the wiki. The readme is short and the [brzo_i2c wiki](https://github.com/pasko-zh/brzo_i2c/wiki) explains many i2c and `brzo_i2c` related stuff.

In general, an i2c bus is not free if either SCA or SCL is low.

I assume your wiring is correct? How big are your pull-up resistors?

I had a look at the datasheet of the PCF8591. On page 20 table 11 "dynamic characteristics" it says: SCL clock frequency MAX 100 kHz. In your code however, you are selecting 400 kHz, `brzo_i2c_start_transaction(0x48,400);` So, you should use 100 kHz at maximum. I guess it is a timing problem for the read command after writing the control byte.

Concerning `Wire.requestFrom(PCF8591, 5)`: 
Behind the scenes this statement *does* read 5 bytes and puts them in a receive buffer, i.e. i2c communication takes place: START, send slave address, read first byte, ..., STOP. You can see this in the [code of the wire library](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/Wire/Wire.cpp#L100), where it calls `twi_readFrom(.)`, and the actual i2c communication in the underlying [esp8266Core code](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/core_esp8266_si2c.c#L181). Note that calls afterwards to `wire.read(.)` does *not* perform any i2c communication, instead it just [returns the bytes from the receive buffer](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/Wire/Wire.cpp#L183).
Now, turning `Wire.requestFrom(PCF8591, 5)` into `brzo_i2c` is very simple:

```
brzo_i2c_start_transaction(0x48,100);
  brzo_i2c_read(buffer,5,false);
bcode = brzo_i2c_end_transaction();
```

However, I would not do seperate transactions for reads and writes, instead I would combine them -- as long as they belong "together". So your code above, where your writing the control byte and then afterwards reading out the corresponding data is the way to go :-)

btw: From your code I am guessing that you are using an analogue temperature sensor. You may use a digital sensor that has an i2c bus interface, e.g., an ADT7420, code snippet with `brzo_i2c` is [here](https://github.com/pasko-zh/brzo_i2c/blob/master/examples/ADT7420.ino)

Comment: Nope. Like i said, the 'wire.h' code works. Anyway, changing the frequency to 100khz does not work. I'm using 4 potentiometers. 10k pullup resistors. i tried with 2 different chips (2x pcf8591). I was thinking that i should do multiple transactions to accomplish what i want. I think the problem is just in some of the lines of the code. Sorry but i can't ask on github . i'm not registered there

Comment: In a simple way : i need to understand how to write "Wire.requestFrom(PCF8591, 5)" with your library. thank for your time.

Comment: @cocco : I've updated my answer to show how to do a read in `brzo_i2c`. Just a side question: Which esp module are you using?

Comment: @cocco : Well, we (i.e. you) need to debug it... try just with the `brzo write` statement alone, to see if the error is still there.

Comment: @cocco : Your pull-up resistor value is far too big for a 3.3V setting and this i2c device. Use 2.2 kOhm or even smaller, minimal 1.5 kOhm, but *not* smaller otherwise current is too strong and may damage either your esp or the i2c device!